# Unable to upload .txt files from ubuntu linux to apache http server using libcurl

Tags: c, http, curl, post, libcurl

I'm trying to upload ".txt" file from Ubuntu Linux to apache http server using libcurl.

I have written the below c code in the Linux system to perform the http post upload to my server

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main(void)
{
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;
  FILE *fd;
  struct stat file_info;

  fd = fopen("/home/shantanu/test.txt", "rb"); /* open file to upload */ 
  if(!fd)
    return 1; /* can't continue */ 

  /* In windows, this will init the winsock stuff */ 
  /* to get the file size */ 
  if(fstat(fileno(fd), &file_info) != 0)
    return 1; /* can't continue */

   curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
   /* get a curl handle */ 
   curl = curl_easy_init();

   if(curl) {
    /* First set the URL that is about to receive our POST. This URL can
       just as well be a https:// URL if that is what should receive the
       data. */ 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://x.x.x.x/dashboard/");

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE,(curl_off_t)file_info.st_size);

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);

    /* Now specify the POST data */ 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,fd);

    /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */ 
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    /* Check for errors */ 
    if(res != CURLE_OK)
      fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
              curl_easy_strerror(res));

    /* always cleanup */ 
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }

  curl_global_cleanup();
  return 0;
}
```

=============================================
in server side inside dashboard folder I have a file named index.php which is having below code to move the file to the location

```
<?PHP
 move_uploaded_file($_FILE['content']['tmp_name'], "test.txt");
?>
```

=================================================================

But the file is not uploading and I get the following o/p

```
*   Trying 1x.6x.32.157...
* Connected to 1x.6x.32.157 (1x.6x.32.157) port 80 (#0)
> POST /dashboard/ HTTP/1.1
Host: 1x.6x.32.157
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 2487
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Expect: 100-continue

< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
* We are completely uploaded and fine
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Fri, 11 May 2018 10:32:20 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.33 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.1.0g PHP/7.2.4
< X-Powered-By: PHP/7.2.4
< Content-Length: 117
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< 
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: content in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\index.php</b> on line <b>2</b><br />
```

Answer (score 0):

[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS.html) wants a `char *`, you're passing it a `FILE *`

Comment: so `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,(char*)fd);` ?

Comment: Thank you Daniel and Hanshenrik , i will try the above.

Comment: No, `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` wants a *string*, not a file descriptor. If you want to read from a file, you need `CUROPT_READFUNCTION`.

Comment: @Shantanu no stop, don't do that, i was just joking (it was a stupid joke at that, sorry), use CURLOPT_READDATA instead of CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS if you can send the file raw as the post body (in which case you must change your php code to something like `$in=fopen("php://input","rb");$dest=fopen("test.txt","wb");stream_copy_to_stream($in,$dest);fclose($in);fclose($dest);` - or if you for some reason need to use $_FILE or use multipart/form-data, ... it is possible to use `multipart/form-data` from the libcurl c api, but i'm not sure how. Stenberg probably does, tho.

Comment: Hi  Daniel & Hanshenrik . Thank you, I was using "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", by default which was not ok, as I was doing file upload. But as you suggested I tried with "multipart/form-data" using libcurl and it is now uploading file with the previous .php code that I asked in question.